# What does the syntax someFunction(abc)(d) mean?

Tags: javascript

How do I interpret this code:

```
  var element = $compile('<p>{{total}}</p>')(scope);
```

Taken from [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

This is the first time I've seen something like:

```
var x = someFunction(abc)(d);
```

I don't know what a set of braces next to each other means in Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this (IIFE) construct in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-iife-construct-in-javascript)

Comment: @Ken this is a completely different topic...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`someFunction(abc)` returns a function. The `(d)` immediately calls the returned function, and passes the parameter `d` to it.

Conceptually, `someFunction(abc)` could be defined as something like below. Here, `someFunction(abc)` returns a function which accepts a parameter (`d`). It alerts the sum of `abc + d`.

```
function someFunction(abc) {
    return function (d) {
        alert(abc + d);
    };
}

var adder = someFunction(10);

adder(2); // 12
adder(3); // 13

// ... or
someFunction(10)(2); // 12
someFunction(10)(3); // 13
```

Experiment here; http://jsfiddle.net/756g3/

---

In your specific case, [`$compile('<p>{{total}}</p>')`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) returns a template function. You're immediately calling that template function, passing the `scope` variable to it.

Comment: So if someFunction ever returns null, an error would get generated. Not sure if using that kind of syntax is a good practice.

Comment: @AndroidDev: Whilst technically true, you don't gain yourself any extra security by doing `var foo = someFunction(abc); foo(d);`. You'd have to check that *every* returned value is a function; `var foo = someFunction(abc); if (typeof foo === 'function') { foo(d); }`, which is excessive.

Comment: @AndroidDev Well the argument is not really valid since if you don't know what a function returns then you will end up with errors anyway. You can do checks but then you write lots of unnecessary code IMHO (unless you know a priori that the function may return `null` and that is a bad practice IMHO: to return objects of different type from one function).

Comment: @freakish Depends. If it's a third party library and you can't necessarily be guaranteed a non-null value, I would not use that syntax.

Comment: @AndroidDev: it completely depends on the situation. If you *know* the function will *always* return a function (like `$compile`), there's **zero** harm in using it. As I said in my previous comment, it's a *direct* replacement for `var foo = someFunction(abc); foo(d);`.

Comment: @AndroidDev Well you can read docs of that third party library. If it is purely documented then you're doing this on your own risk. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its simply invoke the parameter d on the returned (function) from someFunction

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first-order citizens, i.e. you can treat them like other objects, pass them to other functions and return them from other functions. Maybe this will clarify?

```
var fn1 = function(a) {
    var fn2 = function(b) {
        return a+b;
    };
    return fn2;
};
```

Now

```
>> fn1(1)(2)
3
>> var bar = fn1(100)
>> bar(3)
103
>> bar(15)
115
```

What happens is that `fn1` takes an argument `a` and returns a function which will add a passed argument `b` to `a`. I'm bad explanation but I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeFunc() {
    return function (foo) {
        alert(foo);
    };
}

var func = makeFunc();
func('hello');
```

Or, the shorthand for this:

```
makeFunc()('hello');
```

`$compile` returns a function, which is then being invoked.